# What does "XIX" in 'Extraction' mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, extraction

What is the meaning of the "**XIX**" tattoo on the back of the main actor (Jon Foo as 'Mercy') in the movie [*Extraction*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2823574/combined) (2013)?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but that's Roman numerals for the number 19. Does that number have any meaning in the movie?

Comment: I'm in the same boat - "XIX" immediately indicates Roman numerals (in this case, "19") to me, but I can't speak to whether that would have any significance in the movie.

Comment: I bet it's some kind of level to tell the guards how dangerous he is. It is probably from 1 to 20 or so.

Comment: Idk about the movie but [Could it be a Legio XIX tattoo?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legio_XIX)